# ElGamal-based BBS proxy re-encryption implementation?

Tags: encryption, public-key, elgamal-encryption, proxy-re-encryption

are there any available tools/libraries that implement the idea of EIGamal-based proxy re-encryption scheme shown below? Preferably in Golang. Thank you!
[image]
[image]

Source of this picture: [https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~susan/600.641/scribes/lecture17.pdf](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Esusan/600.641/scribes/lecture17.pdf)

Comment: Requests for code are off-topic, and the question is related to [another one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/103330/proxy-re-encryption-based-on-standard-elgamal)